# When I was using RedirectToAction in Asp.net core,My URL Link is using URLEnCode

Tags: controller, asp.net-core-mvc

When I was using RedirectToAction method in my asp .net core project,My Url link goes to `http://localhost:2468/Passage/Details%3FpassageId%3D1`
It should be `http://localhost:2468/Passage/Details?passageId=1`

How can I solve it

```
_ statisticsAppService.UpNumPlus(passageId); 
return RedirectToAction("Details?passageId = " + passageId,"Passage");
```

Comment: What code are you using to do the redirect ?

Comment: ```_
statisticsAppService.UpNumPlus(passageId);
            return RedirectToAction("Details?passageId = " + passageId,"Passage");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `RedirectToAction` method incorrectly. You should pass your route values as a separate parameter and the `RedirectToAction` method will build the querystring for you.

Use [this  overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) of `RedirectToAction`

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues
)
```

So your code should be

```
int passageId = 1;  // Some passageId value you have
return RedirectToAction("Details","Passage", new { passageId = passageId  });
```